# Is there an easy to use way to print a small file as QR-Code on a sheet of paper?

Tags: qr-code, barcode-scanner

Assume I have sensitive information (passwords, private keys,...) that I saved to a file which I encrypted.

Is there an easy to use tool to convert back and forth between a small file (say 0.5kB) and an image (QR code?) that I can print out to have a safe backup?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LaTeX with the ps-tricks and pst-barcode modules, it produces nice QR codes, and yesm we used it exactly for this purpose:  Paper backup of SSH private keys.

Answer (score 0):

Denso Wave of QR code developer distributes software on [their site](http://www.qrcode.com/en/howto/generate.html).
Membership registration on the site is required to obtain it.
Even if you can not print with this, there are various tools regardless of free/commercial, so please search.

The maximum amount of data that can be stored in the QR code is [2953 bytes in binary mode](http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html).
However, it depends on the ability of the scanner to use.
[QR code FAQ #6 Can an image or sound be stored in a QR Code?](http://www.qrcode.com/en/faq.html)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a linux program to do this, called [qr-backup](https://github.com/za3k/qr-backup).

In researching similar programs as part of it, I discovered a number of alternative projects as well. All of these are also linux-only.

- [asc2qr.sh](https://github.com/4bitfocus/asc-key-to-qr-code)
- [paperbackup](https://github.com/intra2net/paperbackup). Focused on GPG/SSH key backup. See also the [paperkey](http://www.jabberwocky.com/software/paperkey/) preprocessor, to reduce the size of keys.
- [qrdump](https://github.com/jerabaul29/qrdump) (incomplete)
- [qrpdf](https://github.com/EmperorArthur/qrpdf)

If your file is very small (0.5KB is a good cutoff), you can generate one single QR code. An example command-line program to generate it is [qrencode](https://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/). Several web converters are also available.